# why AutoFill failed?

Tags: vba, excel

Here I tried to random the colons, however, it tell me cannot autofill, and same thing works for my randomRow()

```
Sub randomCol()

Dim Line As Integer
Line = LastRow + 1
Range("N154").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RAND()"

Dim randomRange As String
randomRange = "N" & Line & ":BF" & Line
MsgBox randomRange
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(randomRange), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("N2:BF" & Line).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range("N" & LastRow + 1), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("N1:BF" & Line)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .Apply
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Function LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row it is a function End Function

Answer (score 0):

AutoFill method requires that the destination must include the source range. Proper Syntax for autofill as follows for example only.

```
Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2") 
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20") 
sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

Accordingly I have modified your program and hope it should work fine.

```
Sub randomCol()
    Dim Line As Integer
    Line = LastRow + 1
    Range("N154").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RAND()"
    Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N154")  'Changed you can set the range required by you.
    Dim randomRange As String
    randomRange = "N" & Line & ":BF" & Line
    Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("n1:BF154") 'Set fill range appropriately but should include source range
    MsgBox randomRange
  'changed    
  'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(randomRange), Type:=xlFillDefault 

   SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
    Range("N2:BF" & Line).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N" & LastRow + 1), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("N1:BF" & Line)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Neo Zhang Working copy has been uploaded to dropbox for your viewing and tweaking. My approach is to find out the shortcoming in OP's Code and try to rectify it. There are always more than one solutions for a problem. [Auto Fill  Failure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbnjykctx0fngtg/Auto%20fill%20failure%20VBA.xlsm?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

**edit** after OP's specification that `LastRow` is a function returning `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row`

the destination must include the source range, while the latter is "N154" and the former are cells in row `Line` between columns "N" and "BF", so it'd work only if `Line` is 154.

moreover it's best to define both `Line` and `LastRow()` as of `Long` type instead of `Integer`

so that your code could change like follows:

```
Sub randomCol()    
Dim Line As Long

Line = Lastrow + 1
Range("N" & Line).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RAND()"

Dim randomRange As String
randomRange = "N" & Line & ":BF" & Line
MsgBox randomRange
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(randomRange), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("N2:BF" & Line).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N" & Line), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("N1:BF" & Line)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .Apply
End With    

End Sub

Function LastRow() As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

but you may also consider:

- to avoid selections and activation
- there's no need for `Autofill` actually, since you're simply pasting a formula

so your code can become:

```
Sub randomCol2()
    Dim Line As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Line = .Cells(.Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Columns("N:BF").Rows(Line).FormulaR1C1 = "=RAND()"

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N" & Line), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range("N1:BF" & Line)
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
 it is a function

Comment: I see. I edited answer to include this information. But the issue remains the same: _"the destination must include the source range"_, while the latter is "N154" and the former are cells in row `Line` between columns "N" and "BF", so it'd work only if `Line` is 154.

Comment: @NeoZhang: did you get through it?